# Send CSV from Kafka to Spark Streaming

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka

i'm trying to send a csv file from kafka to a spark streaming application and i don't know how to do it. I read many post here but no one helped me.

I would like that my kafka producer send the csv and split it later in the application (consumer), but it is not important. I tried to create an RDD and send it to spark. **This worked for normal string messages but it didn't to csv**.

This is my producer:

```
message =sc.textFile("/home/guest/host/Seeds.csv")      
producer.send('test', message)
```

And my spark consumer:

```
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
```

`kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer", {'test': 1})
data = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])`
`counts = data.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(";")) \`

```
.map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
```

The problem is that by sending the csv, spark streamming don't recieve any event.
Can someone help me with the formats or concepts?

Im running producer and consumer in a notebook with python under a docker container.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your producer, message is a RDD(collection of csv file lines distributed across cluster) which is lazily evaluated i.e. it would not do anything until you perform action on it. So you need to collect RDD before sending to Kafka.
Please see below link.
[how to properly use pyspark to send data to kafka broker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337086/how-to-properly-use-pyspark-to-send-data-to-kafka-broker)

Answer (score 0):

In my work i convert any csv to json,

here is example how you can make it on your knee (i mean with out any `import json`)

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import time,csv

'''
input csv example

AT,BE,BG,CH,CY,CZ,DE,DK,EE,ES,FI,FR,EL,HR,HU,IE,IT,LT,LU,LV,NL,NO,PL,PT,RO,SI,SK,SE,UK
0.15104895104895097,0.155978142670726,0.0,0.132959173102667,0,0.0261248185776488,0.0314454263905056,0.0,0.0,0.22130378970001602,0.0,0.0881265984931488,0.09026049932169501,0.056874262941565,0.0841602727424313,0.0494006197388216,0.0912473405767843,0.0,0.0656217442366246,0.0,0.0432966804004962,0.0,0.0,0.19138755980861197,0.0,0.0521335743946527,0.0,0.0,0.0434660616908725

'''

# create producer to kafka connection
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='89.218.20.173:9092')
# define *.csv file and a char that divide value
fname = "input.csv"
divider_char = ','
# open file
with open(fname) as fp:  
    # read header (first line of the input file)
    line = fp.readline()
    header = line.split(divider_char)

    #loop other data rows 
    line = fp.readline()    
    while line:
        # start to prepare data row to send
        data_to_send = ""
        values = line.split(divider_char)
        len_header = len(header)
        for i in range(len_header):
            data_to_send += "\""+header[i].strip()+"\""+":"+"\""+values[i].strip()+"\""
            if i<len_header-1 :
                data_to_send += ","
        data_to_send = "{"+data_to_send+"}"

        '''
        example of outputs is valid JSON row 
        {
            "AT":"0.148251748251748",
            "BE":"0.052603706790461",
                ...
            "SE":"0.0826699344612236",
            "UK":"0.10951678628072099"
        }
        '''

        # send data via producer
        producer.send('test', bytes(data_to_send, encoding='utf-8'))
        line = fp.readline()
        # А это так))) на всякий случай
        #time.sleep(1)
producer.close()
```

then you can use next answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47457985/6796393